# Ebsopen fails to load ebsilon model sometimes

Tags: c#

I'm trying to execute ebsilon model in c# using ebsilon library "ebsopen". 
Model loading is behaving in an abnormal way, sometimes it loads the model perfectly fine but sometimes it gives an exception and fails to load the same model.

I've double checked and using the same way as defined by Ebsilon to load and close the model in c# using "ebsopen" as defined at this link http://help.ebsilon.com/EN/Getting%20Started%20with%20EBSOpen.html
Seems like it holds the model somewhere in memory even after closing it, which causes the failure on next load.

```
//Line to open model
eModel = application.Open({ebsmodel}, true);
//Line to close model
eModel.Close();
```

Is there some memory that needs to be cleared even after ebsilon model is closed?